# Reclassify Tool Resulting in NoData where Input has Data

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, reclassify

Software: ArcGIS Pro 2

I am having an issue with the Reclassify tool. I am attempting to reclassify raster data into three classes so that I can do a habitat suitability analysis. When I use the Reclassify tool on some raster data I have (not *all* raster data I have) the resulting reclassified raster has several NoData strips in seemingly random areas across my study area. These strips are not NoData areas within my Input raster. Please see examples below:

Input Raster:

[image]

Reclassified Raster (white = NoData):

[image]

I haven't been able to figure out exactly what could cause this, mainly because I'm not sure where to start. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue, but Esri grid has limited character number, you need to reduce the length of the output raster name or use `.tif' or '.img' extension if you want to keep long names.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I shortened all the output names and it worked! A little strange since one of the output rasters that did work initially had a 12+ long name. Post it and I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Glad it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes reclassification and other spatial analyses can act strangely due to strange reasons such as raster names. Esri grid has limited character numbers, so you have two options:

1. Reduce the length of the output raster name if you want to stick with Esri grid
2. Or use `.tif` or `.img` extensions if you want to keep long names.